# ULA/Ball Aerospace Intern Sport Rocket

Tags: rockets, ula, performance, amateur-rocketry

So I've seen ULA post about their intern rocket launch a couple of weekends ago and was curious:

What are the performance specs on the motors used for the first/second stage? (Class, quantity, etc.)

For reference, here's a video of the rocket I'm asking about (~1 minute):

Thanks!

Comment: Most of these should probably be separate questions, since there's no particular relation between the answers except that they're on the same general topic.

Comment: That's fair -- edited to be just a single specific question.